# Merge two excel tables given a common characteristic

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, merge, links

Suppose there are 2 excel tables with following information:

First table:

[image]

Second table:

[image]

The task is to find for each cost center an employee(allocate cost center to employee).

How can I do it in excel?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a [VLOOKUP](https://spreadsheeto.com/vlookup/)
You can look up a value from one table, and populate it in another field.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use vlookup but this will require the index field (cost center) to be on the left of your return value (employee). If you swap B and C columns of the second table, you can use vlookup with this formula in F2 of the 1st table: =vlookup(E2, Table2!B2:Table2!C,2,FALSE)

Otherwise, this formula will work without changing the current tables. It uses the index, match method. Put this into F2 of the first table: =index(A:F, MATCH(E2, Table2!B:Table2!B,0),3)

The benefit of index match is that you can define what column you want to return by simply changing the return column value (3) above.

The limitation of both methods is that they don't handle multiple values well. You'll get only the first or last value depending on your implementation. Not sure if this is an issue, but SGRR70 has 3 employees in the example above.

Will need clarification if you're looking for a specific return value

Comment: Yes, as you've noticed, SGRR70 has 3 employees and I was looking for all 3 results after filtering. If VLOOKUP doesn't work for multiple values, whta method can work?